# optional local variables in rails partial templates: how do I get out of the (defined? foo) mess?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I've been a bad kid and used the following syntax in my partial templates to set default values for local variables if a value wasn't explicitly defined in the :locals hash when rendering the partial --

```
<% foo = default_value unless (defined? foo) %>
```

This seemed to work fine until recently, when (for no reason I could discern) non-passed variables started behaving as if they had been defined to nil (rather than undefined).

As has been pointed by various helpful people on SO, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html says *not* to use

```
defined? foo
```

and instead to use

```
local_assigns.has_key? :foo
```

I'm trying to amend my ways, but that means changing a lot of templates.

Can/should I just charge ahead and make this change in all the templates?  Is there any trickiness I need to watch for?  How diligently do I need to test each one?

Comment: This question is quite old, and all answers seemed to be outdated, because the current [Action View documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html), specifically says it's okay to use `definded? foo`: _"Alternatively, you could also use defined? headline to first check if the variable has been assigned before using it."_

Answer (score 361, accepted):

I do this:

```
<% some_local = default_value if local_assigns[:some_local].nil? %>
```

Comment: Though I really like the compact syntax of hgimenez's suggestion (above), this approach has the advantage of being very clear re: what's going on.  (Still has the downside of not letting you pass nil as a value for the local)

Comment: What's your use case for wanting to pass nil?

Comment: Oh, I don't have a specific case in mind.  Just trying to understand the full implications.  

This reminded me to accept this answer :-)

Comment: To get over the nil issue, I'm copying the code from the OP's link (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html) <% if local_assigns.has_key? :headline %>
  Headline: <%= headline %>
<% end %> -- has_key avoids the nil / false situation, and probably can be shortened to one line like the answer here

Comment: Please check Pablo's answer: `local_assigns.fetch` perfectly handles even keys with nil value. It returns a default only if the key is **not** set at all.

Comment: I know this is old. But I want to add a new solution `<% some_local ||= default_value %>`

Answer (score 183):

Since `local_assigns` is a hash, you could also use [fetch](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) with the optional `default_value`.

```ruby
local_assigns.fetch :foo, default_value
```

This will return `default_value` if `foo` wasn't set.

WARNING:

Be careful with `local_assigns.fetch :foo, default_value` when `default_value` is a method, as it will be called anyway in order to pass its result to `fetch`.

If your `default_value` is a method, you can wrap it in a block: `local_assigns.fetch(:foo) { default_value }` to prevent its call when it's not needed.

Comment: It's worth saying it explicitly: `nil` values are preserved here. If the hash contains `:foo` mapped to `nil`, then `fetch` it will return `nil`. That is, at least on my v1.9.3. I don't remember how 1.8 behaved.

Comment: That's totally right. It remembers me the problem for `local_assigns[:foo] || default_value`, when foo returns a falsy value, the `default_value` will be used instead. It is usually a problem for Memoization `@some_value ||= expensive_method` if the method returns a falsy value, it will always be executed.

Comment: Anyone who doesn't understand why this is the best answer hasn't used ruby long enough. Bravo Pablo!

Comment: An optimization is the following, so that you only have to call this once at the top of your template, instead of using the 'fetch guard' on every use of the variable.

`foo ||= local_assigns[:foo] = local_assigns.fetch(:foo, default_value)`

Comment: I was wondering why it didn't work, I assumed it created the variable too, but we still have to use the returned value: `foo = local_assigns.fetch :foo, true`

Comment: If you don't want to repeat yourself every time (maybe you are checking foo multiple times, you can do `<% foo = local_assigns.fetch(:foo, foo_default_value) %>` at the top of your partial.

Answer (score 89):

How about

```
<% foo ||= default_value %>
```

This says "use `foo` if it is not nil or true. Otherwise assign `default_value` to foo"

Comment: I'm not sure this works as foo isn't defined unless it's passed in through the locals hash.

Comment: Yeah, it works. There is some magic that allows you to do this with undefined locals.

Comment: This works, but if you have default values like this, maybe it's a sign that you should use a helper?

Comment: No magic here. More resources on the subject: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/fe4fbc48e19105cd/bf7f73380e285aff?lnk=gst&q=Or+equal

Comment: I really like this version since the syntax is so compact.  I suppose the big downside is that it means you can't pass nil or false as a value for the local, though, since it will be overwritten by the default.

Comment: @brahn, that's a good point. In fact, this should be avoided if `foo` is a boolean. It may rightfully have the value of `false`, and be overridden by `default_value` accidentally.

Comment: Please (also) check Pablo's answer: `local_assigns.fetch` perfectly handles even keys with nil value. It returns a default only if the key is **not** set at all.

Comment: @hgmnz isn't this behavior only a problem if the default value is `true`?

Comment: Note that `<%= foo || 'default' %>` doesn't work, but `<%= foo ||= 'default' %>` works fine.

Answer (score 13):

I think this should be repeated here (from http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html):

If you need to find out whether a certain local variable has been assigned a value in a particular render call, you need to use the following pattern:

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :headline %>
  Headline: <%= headline %>
<% end %>
```

Testing using defined? headline will not work. This is an implementation restriction.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I use:

```
<% variable ||= "" %>
```

in my partial.  
I don't have idea if that is good but for my is OK

Comment: This actually works quite well. Works for undefined and when passing `nil` as a local in the partial call as well.

Comment: Ah, reading down below, this will fail if `variable` is a boolean and you need to set it to `false`. It will use the default value instead of using the `false` value. USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.

Comment: This is the cleanest way for anything without truthy confusion.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old thread but here's my small contribution: i would use `local_assigns[:foo].presence` in a **conditional** inside the partial. 
Then i set `foo` only when needed in the render call:

```
<%= render 'path/to/my_partial', always_present_local_var: "bar", foo: "baz" %>
```

Have a look at te [official Rails guide here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence). Valid from RoR 3.1.0.

Comment: I can't see any real difference between `local_assigns[:foo]` and `local_assigns[:foo].presence`. Either one will return `nil` if the key does not exist in the hash and the value if it does exist.

Answer (score 3):

This is a derivative of Pablo's answer.  This allows me to set a default ('full'), and in the end, 'mode' is set in both local_assigns and an actual local variable.

haml/slim:

```
- mode ||= local_assigns[:mode] = local_assigns.fetch(:mode, 'full')
```

erb:

```
<% mode ||= local_assigns[:mode] = local_assigns.fetch(:mode, 'full') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a better option that allows for multiple default variables:

```
<% options = local_assigns.reverse_merge(:include_css => true, :include_js => true) %>
<%= include_stylesheets :national_header_css if options[:include_css] %>
<%= include_javascripts :national_header_js if options[:include_js] %>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby 2.5

#### Erb

It's possible, but you must to declare your default values in the scope.

**VARIABLE** the word for replacement.

```
# index.html.erb
...
<%= render 'some_content', VARIABLE: false %>
...

# _some_content.html.erb
...
<% VARIABLE = true if local_assigns[:VARIABLE].nil? %>
<% if VARIABLE %>
    <h1>Do you see me?</h1>
<% end %>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

More intuitive and compact:

`<% some_local = default_value unless local_assigns[:some_local] %>`

Comment: I think this will fail if you call the partial with `:locals => {:some_local => false}`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to pass local variable to partial each time you call it you do this:

```
<% local_param = defined?(local_param) ? local_param : nil %>
```

This way you avoid `undefined variable` error. This will allow you to call your partial with/without local variables.

Comment: OR local_param = local_param if defined?(local_param)

Answer (score -6):

A helper can be created to look like this:

```
somearg = opt(:somearg) { :defaultvalue }
```

Implemented like:

```
module OptHelper
  def opt(name, &block)
    was_assigned, value = eval(
      "[ local_assigns.has_key?(:#{name}), local_assigns[:#{name}] ]", 
      block.binding)
    if was_assigned
      value
    else
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

See [my blog](http://www.method-missing.com/2009/09/argument-defaults-for-partials-in-rails.html) for details on how and why.

Note that this solution does allow you to pass nil or false as the value without it being overridden.