# How to have an optional local variable in a partial template in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was thinking that at the top of my partial I would have something like this

```
<% optional_width = default_value unless (defined? optional_width)
```

But I've had inconsistent results with this, I'm thinking this is not a good way to do this. What is the "correct" way to do this in rails?

Comment: possible duplicate of [optional local variables in rails partial templates: how do I get out of the (defined? foo) mess?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060561/optional-local-variables-in-rails-partial-templates-how-do-i-get-out-of-the-de)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Read the *Passing local variables to sub templates* section in the [ActionView::Base docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html)

Basically it says you should use this pattern:

```
<% if local_assigns.has_key? :headline %>
  Headline: <%= headline %>
<% end %>
```

For you, this might translate to something like:

```
<div style="width: <%= local_assigns.has_key?(:optional_width) ? optional_width : 500 %>px;">
  <!-- filler -->
</div>
```

### important!

According to the docs

> Testing using `defined? headline` will not work. This is an implementation restriction.

Answer (score 3):

Although not exactly equivalent to your code, that's usually done with `||` operator.

```
<%  optional_width ||= default_value  %>
```

This is equivalent to `optional_width = optional_width || default_value`.  Due to [shot-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), if `optional_with` is "true", i.e. it's defined, and not `nil`, the right-hand part becomes equal to it, and `default_value` is not even computed.  Otherwise, right-hand part would be equal to `default_value`.  That's essentially what you want to do.

Ok, I admit that it may not work for partial's locals.  The particular situation I can imagine is that if in first render call the `optional_width` variable was set to some value, and in the consequent call to `render` it is not mentioned at all while keeping its value from the first run.  Can't do such a check right now, though.

Comment: Pavel Shved, this is ordinarily fine but you need to understand the underpinnings of ActionView. As noted in the API, your solution will not work reliably. For more details, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html :)