# Forward Partials to Partials? (Rails 2.3.x)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

Instead of using the full name of my partials (/controller/wherever/partial) I would like to put a dummy partial that forwards all of the locals variables to the real partial. Is there any way to access the locals variables from a partial (aside from the obvious, by name one-by-one)? That way I could do:

```
 <%=render :partial=>"controller/wherever/partial", :locals=>self_locals} -%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
:locals => local_assigns
```

Came across this today, wanted default value for a local

[optional local variables in rails partial templates: how do I get out of the (defined? foo) mess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060561/optional-local-variables-in-rails-partial-templates-how-do-i-get-out-of-the-def)

Comment: Wow. I'll try that. Didn't have my hopes up for this question, really. Thanks!