# Ruby: Using a not defined variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

How can I make something like this?

```
1.9.3p286 :006 > defined? activated_flag
 => nil 
1.9.3p286 :007 > puts (activated_flat ? "activated!" : "no activated")
```

I would like to see here `no activated`, but instead I have:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `activated_flat' for main:Object
  from (irb):7
  from /Users/fguillen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not using `defined?`:

```
puts (defined?(activated_flat) ? "activated!" : "no activated")
#=> no activated
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I have found is adding a *fallback initialization* like:

```
activated_flag ||= false
```

But as I'm using this variable in `erb` partials this *fallback initialization* looks ugly.

Comment: Why not make the partial's caller pass everything? A partial is a method and methods have defined interfaces, if someone calls a method without supplying all the parameters that its interface demands then the caller will get the errors that they deserve.

Comment: Exactly @muistooshort, and what I'm missing is the [param default value functionality](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#Default_Values) but for the partial definition, which would be very helpful in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, Rails likes to pretend that partials aren't functions so you have to do it the [dumb ugly way](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html#label-Passing+local+variables+to+sub+templates). And a similar question (which might even be a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/q/2060561/479863. Shame that partials (and ERB templates in general) aren't explicitly functions (hmm, am I reverting to Lisp in my old age? Ha!).